# PowerShell Download Txt File from WebSite

Tags: powershell

I am facing an issue in downloading the txt file from a website. The script below downloads the http code instead of the actual txt file and its contents.

`$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebClient.DownloadFile("https://thegivebackproject.org/CheckStatus.txt", "D:\CheckStatus.txt")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer**

The server is doing browser sniffing to send different responses based on the `User-Agent` header in your request. You can get the response you want by sending a canned user agent string:

```bsh
$useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36"
Invoke-WebRequest -URI https://thegivebackproject.org/CheckStatus.txt -OutFile c:\temp\CheckStatus.txt -UserAgent $useragent
```

**Long Answer**

The server responding to the url you're hitting is doing browser sniffing to decide what content to return. If you give it a `User-Agent` header that it recognises it will return the response you're expecting (i.e. the literal text "Azeemkhan-WaseemRaza").

If you don't include a `User-Agent` header (and `$WebClient.DownloadFile` *doesn't* include one), the server is responding with a html page instead.

You can see this behaviour yourself if you install a HTTP trace tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler). When you hit the page in a browser you see this HTTP request and response  pair:

**request**

```
GET https://thegivebackproject.org/CheckStatus.txt HTTP/1.1
Host: thegivebackproject.org
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Cookie: SPSI=ee952ba44e33e958f963807ede78624b
```

**response**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 12 Nov 2019 08:13:57 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 20
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Thu, 07 Nov 2019 16:15:48 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Cache: MISS

Azeemkhan-WaseemRaza
```

but when you use `$WebClient.DownloadFile` you see this instead:

**request**

```
GET https://thegivebackproject.org/CheckStatus.txt HTTP/1.1
Host: thegivebackproject.org
```

**response**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 12 Nov 2019 08:14:21 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: SPSI=9c24f8993046ef610e25cc727c4a4ae2; Path=/
Set-Cookie: adOtr=obsvl; Expires=Thu, 2 Aug 2001 20:47:11 UTC; Path=/
Set-Cookie: UTGv2=D-h4d40f620bfdd6c3b77b035ee99f96621134; Expires=Wed, 11-Nov-20 08:14:21 GMT; Path=/
cache-control: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate, private,  max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Cache: MISS
Accept-Ranges: bytes

5908
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>StackPath</title>
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
... etc...
```

The workaround is to include a recognised `User-Agent` header in your request, which is easier to to if you use `Invoke-WebRequest` like @BiNZGi suggested, rather than the WebClient class - see the "short answer" above for the code.

Also, note that this sniffing behaviour with the `User-Agent` is specific to "thegivebackproject.org" website and isn't necessarily true for other websites - you don't *always* need to include a `User-Agent` header as a rule of thumb.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation of the issue. It really helped.

Comment: It was running fine on my machine but when I took the script to Azure VM it stopped working. I am again getting the html file instead of the text file. Basically, it's a security service redirection html which says There is a redirect to prevent attachs.This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks.This process is automatic, you will be redirected to the requested URL once the validation process is complete. Is there a way to wait for redirection to complete? Thanks

Comment: You might have to speak to the site owner to ask them what their requirements are for you to be able to make automated calls. It's not something you can necessarily reverse-engineer from trial and error.

Comment: they want me to validate that the txt file with content is served to ensure the website is up and running.

Comment: problem is that content is served via StackPath CDN. I have reverted to loading the page directly in IE and then validating that required content is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the easier [Invoke-WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest):

```
Invoke-WebRequest -URI https://thegivebackproject.org/CheckStatus.txt -OutFile D:\CheckStatus.txt
```